# str_get_html doesn't work and return blank

Tags: php

I got a blank screen after I run below code

```
<?php include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = getSslPage('https://www.reddit.com/r/nottheonion/comments/3aev89/kim_jongun_claims_to_have_cured_aids_ebola_and/');


function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$html = str_get_html($html);

echo $html;
```

the hardest part of debugging it is it work sometime with other url. I wonder why coz the pages have the same DOM structure. Anyone have idea why is it happening?

Comment: So what exactly is `str_get_html()`? It isn't a core PHP function

Comment: @MarkBaker Create a DOM object from a string http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Well the simple_html_dom function str_get_html() returns an __object__, not necessarily one that you can echo, unless it has a magic __toString() method.... what do you expect to see when you echo it?

Comment: You could try `echo $html->plaintext();`

Comment: @MarkBaker No I wouldn't want to do plaintext, I want its html. U can try to run above code with this url https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/3a53qw/grandmother_mother_and_daughter/ it worked.

Comment: If you just want the html, then you have that before you're converting it to a DOM object

Comment: @MarkBaker I wouldn't want it all, the reason why I do str_get_html is because I want to continue to use the method like find() to get certain part of the pages.

Comment: @MarkBaker Have u tried the url I gave? I wonder why it work with str_get_html.

Answer (score 11):

It is because the html string is too large and simple_html_dom has a maximum limit that it can parse. Here's what you can do to increase the limit.

Open the `simple_html_dom.php` and change this line

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000);
```

to something more.. Try

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 60000000); // add a zero at the end
```

This should solve the problem. Let me know, if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

The source code like this:

```
defined('MAX_FILE_SIZE') || define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

You can define MAX_FILE_SIZE before calling the file;

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000);
require_once ( 'simple-html-dom.php' );
```